# External Profile Support

Tags: profile, joomla, html

I am receiving a warning when I enter CiviCRM which seems to indicate that I have something called "external profile support" set.  Where do I find this option enabled?   I have looked but cannot find it.  I would appreciate an emailed answer if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's in **Administer menu » System Settings » Misc**, and it's labeled "Accept profile submissions from external sites".

That's a little obtuse, but most system warnings have a link on the System Status page, at **Administer menu » Administration Console » System Status**.  See screenshot:

[image]